# Friends' friends

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

If I'm friends with Alice, and Alice is friends with Bob, is there a specific term for my relationship with Bob, or is it just "a friend of a friend"?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41252/is-there-a-single-word-for-a-friend-of-a-friend
Does this answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a single word for a "friend of a friend"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41252/is-there-a-single-word-for-a-friend-of-a-friend)

Comment: "Friend of a friend" is probably most idiomatic.